# Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'originalImage'

Tags: swift, xcode

im trying to use imagePickerController and im getting this weird error "Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'originalImage'"

I've used this code before but im not sure why im getting this error this time, or how to fix it.

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) 
    {
        guard let pickImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }
        
        photoImageView.image = pickImage
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

please help!

heres the full code:

```
class AddCardViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    
    private let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    let defaultImage = UIImage(named: "q")
    
    private var newCard: Card?
    
    private func updateSaveButtonState() {
        let questionText = questionField.text ?? ""
        let answerText = answerField.text ?? ""
        
        saveButton.isEnabled = !questionText.isEmpty && !answerText.isEmpty
    }
    
    public func getCard() -> Card? {
        return newCard
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        photoImageView.image = defaultImage
        questionField.delegate = self
        answerField.delegate = self
    }
    
    @IBAction func pickImage(_ sender: Any) {
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let pickImage:UIImage = info [.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }
        
        photoImageView.image = pickImage
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func alertMessage(_ message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add a card", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "okie dokie", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code and it works for me.

It could be that you don't have an IBOutlet for `photoImageView`

If it isn't that, then I would need to see the rest of your `imagePickerController` code to understand what's wrong.

Comment: i've used this code before and its worked fine but this time im getting an error, i added the full code now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was using Swift 4 when I should've been using Swift 5.